# Console log not shoping variables I want it to show

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a project for school, and I'm trying to make some sort of store where you can buy fireworks.

I've managed to load in several items from a JSON file, and now I'm trying to make the shopping cart work. For this shopping cart, I want a function that can add the selected product's variables to a string and paste them in the cart.

For starters, I want to print the pressed data to the console, but it isn't working and I don't know what to do, as I'm getting `S.fn.init {}` in the console.

[image: screenshot]

As you can see in the image, I would like the product's name and price and add it to the cart eventually.

This is the HTML I'm using for the cards you can see.

```js
function addToCart() {
  var productInfo = $(this.dataset);
  console.log($(productInfo.name))
};

//toggle function
function toggle() {
  $('.keyboardViewSection').toggle();
  $('.touchViewSection').toggle();

  var x = document.getElementById("toggleBtn");
  if (x.innerHTML === "Keyboard View") {
    x.innerHTML = "Touch View";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Keyboard View";
  }
}



$(document).ready(function() {

  //Touchview productCard output
  $(function() {
    $.getJSON("assets/products/sample_products.json", function(response) {
      $.each(response.data, function(i, el) {
        let card = $($('#productCard-template').html());
        card.find('#cardName').html(el.name);
        card.find('#cardPrice').html('&euro;' + el.price);
        card.find('.productItem').attr('data-price', el.price)
          .attr('data-article-number', el.article_number)
          .attr('data-id', el.id)
          .attr('data-name', el.name)
          .attr('data-stock', el.stock)
          .attr('data-categorie', el.categorie);
        $('#touchViewProducts').append(card);
      });
    });
  });

  //KeyboardView Datatable output
  $('[data-selected]')
  $('#data-table').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "ajax": "assets/products/sample_products.json",
    "columns": [{
        "data": "article_number"
      },
      {
        "data": "name"
      },
      {
        "data": "stock"
      },
      {
        "data": "price",
        render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 2, '&euro; ')
      },
      {
        "defaultContent": "<button class='addToCart'>Add to Cart</button><button class='addFree'>Add Free</button>"
      }
    ]
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-3 productCard" id="productCard">
  <a href="#" class="productItem" onclick="addToCart()">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="assets/images/Firecracker.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width: 100%; height: 8vh;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="height: 6vh; max-width: 20ch;">
          <p id="cardName"> </p>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="height: 50%">
          <b><p id="cardPrice"></p></b>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not much familiar with jQuery but probably you should remove the `$` from `$(productInfo.name)`. Should look like: `console.log(productInfo.name)`

Comment: You need to be more specific about your issue so the developers can help you. Sharing your whole code is helpful but it is like doing a code review.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues:

You need to remove this `onclick="addToCart()"` and add it here:
`.attr('data-categorie', el.categorie).on('click',addToCard);`

Then change `function addToCart(){` to `function addToCart(event){`

and finally, instead of using `$(this.dataset)` try using `$(this).data()`.

You could also use `$(event.target).data()`.

You might also want the test if the `<a>` tag or `<img>` tag was the event.target. If it was the image, then you can use `$(event.target).parent().data()`.